# JQgrid total amount row

Tags: json, jqgrid, sum

iv seen an example by @Oleg for row total sum in jqgrid but i tried to apply it and it wont work i have the following grid i need to calculate the amount value for it.

```
colNames: ['ID', 'FTE', 'Workload'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 200, align: 'left', hidden: true },

                { name: 'FTEValue', index: 'FTEValue', width: 200, align: 'left', formatter: 'number' },
                { name: 'Workload', index: 'Workload', width: 200, align: 'left' },



    caption: "Activity FTE",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    scroll: 0,
    rowNum: 100,
    sortname: 'ID',
    pager: '#pager',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
    height: '100%',
    footerrow: true,
    jsonReader: { root: "GridData", page: "CurrentPage", total: "TotalPages", records: "TotalRecords", repeatitems: false, id: "0" }
};



DutyFTEGrid.prototype.SetupGrid = function (selector) {
    jQuery(selector).html('<table id="grid"></table><div id="pager"></div>');
    var grid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid(this.gridConfiguration);

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { edit: false, add: false, search: false }, {}, {},
    { // Delete parameters
        ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        mtype: "DELETE",
        serializeDelData: function () {
            return ""; 
        },
        onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
            params.url = serviceURL + 'DutyFTE(' + encodeURIComponent(postdata) + ')/';
        }
    });

    var grid = $("#grid");
    var sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'FTE', false, 'sum');
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { DriverEn: 'Total FTE:', FTEValue: sum });
};
```

Oleg your help please, i have tried your example but it didnt work for some reason.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to place in the footer [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) and [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) methods:

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'amount', false, 'sum');

grid.jqGrid('footerData','set', {ID: 'Total:', amount: sum});
```

The `getCol` can be used to calculate the sum of all numbers from the 'amount' column and with respect of `footerData` you can place at the bottom of the `'ID'` column the text "Total:" and at the bottom of `'amount'` column.

**UPDATED**: Probably you have problems because you place the code in the wrong place. The most safe place for the code is `loadComplete` event handler. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum.htm).

Comment: thank you man, i tired it but i dont know why the result always 0 !

Comment: i was mistaken with the col name, anyway i put the correct one now and there no value at all appear, note: the values inside the cells are float like 0.3

Comment: @Madi: If you want to calculate the data as float you should define float formatter in the column. Just add `formatter: 'number'` in the 'amount' column. If if will not help you should append your question with full jqGrid definition and the test data.

Comment: yeah it does change the format but i still get the total 0:00 :S i don't know why, maybe it does the calculation before the rows are initialized ?

Comment: i have updated the question with the fill jqgrid i need to calculate the FTEValue column

Comment: @Madi: I updated my answer and included [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum.htm) for you.

Comment: big thanks man for your help and example, the gird never enters the loadComplete function idk why, but i have change it with gridComplete and now its just working fine. thx again m8

Comment: @Madi: The `loadComplete` is the last event handler in [the execution order](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#execution_order) so I personally prefer to use it. Moreover it has one parameter - the data in the same format in which the data are send from the server. You can even send from the server any additional information and read it inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: don't forget to set grid option -> footerrow: true

Comment: What if the cells with have value with other character? Something like sum of prices and the cells will looks like this: $100.00? 
Then when you use this functionality the result will always be NaN.

Comment: @user3850805: It's better you ask separate question where you exactly describe what you do: how you fill the grid and how the column is defined. If you do all correctly, `getCol` works correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

Total of a price column:

```
//Count total for a price column
var total = 0;
$('#table tr').each(function(){

    //cells that contains the price
    var tdprice = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html();

    //Sum it up!
    if (isNaN(tdprice)){ total += parseInt(tdprice); }
});

alert(total + "$");
```