# add rows to jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way I can append search result to the table? What I want to achieve is
add more buttons in the bottom of table and let list grow as they click on the button.
It's like facebook more button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) to add any custom button the the [navigator bar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator). With respect of [footerrow: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option you can add "summary" row in the grid body. Using `footerData` method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393740/315935)) you can set any HTML code fragment in the row. To add *data* to the grid you can use [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods), but I would not recommend you to mix the rows with data and the rows having buttons only.