# How to add two footer row in jqgrid using userdata?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using this jqgrid

```
        $("#griglia-navgrid").jqGrid( { 
        url: 'search.do?report='+r,
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:[ ...    ],              
            colModel:[ ...    ],
            rowNum:50,
        rowList:[20,50,100],
        pager: '#pager',
        autowidth:true,
        height:'auto',
            viewrecords: true,
        sortname: "MATNR",
            sortorder: "asc",
            footerrow : true,
            userDataOnFooter: true, 
            jsonReader: {
                root:"INVDATA",
                page: "CURRPAGE",
                total: "TOTALPAGES",
                records: "TOTALRECORDS",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "0",
                userdata: "USERDATA",
            }
        }); //jqGrid
```

On server side I calculate the totals and I use "userdata" like this:

```
"userdata":{"total":1234,"name":"Totals"}
```

And it's works. Now I need to show 2 footer row with totals. And i try something like this:

```
"userdata":[{"total":1234,"name":"Totals"},{"total":5678,"name":"Totals"}]
```

But does not work. Is it possible add two footer rows using "userdata"? How can I do this?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697523/how-to-create-two-footer-rows-in-jqgrid/13703037#13703037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703037/315935) as a basis of the solution which you need. It shows how to add two rows in the footer.

If you examine the source code of jqGrid for the usage of `userDataOnFooter` option you would find that in case of usage `datatype: "json"` it's only [one line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L1557) of code:

```js
if(ts.p.userDataOnFooter) { self.jqGrid("footerData","set",ts.p.userData,true); }
```

So jqGrid just get the value of `userData` parameter (the `userdata` in the JSON response from the server) and uses it as the parameter of `footerData` method. So you can just remove `userDataOnFooter` option and uses the approach described in the referenced above answer to add two rows in the footer with the information from `userData`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I'm almost done :D But one thing, when I create the second row, I have to fill it field by field like this: " $newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_invdate]").text("Grand Total:"); " ?

Comment: @GiacomoSavioli: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The grid from my demo had the column with `name: "invdate"`. So I used the selector `">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_invdate]"` to fill the cell in the column `invdate` in the second row. You need replace `invdate` part of the selector with another name from `colModel` which you use.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain clear. To fill the 1st row i used $this.jqGrid("footerData", "set", data[0]); I thought to fill the second row, I could use something like this. But I could not, so I used:  $newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_VRKME]").text(data[i].VRKME); for each column. Another question, is it possible to add n footer row?

Comment: @GiacomoSavioli: Sorry, but I still don't understand your current question. Do you can now successfully add the second footer and fill it or you still have some problems?

Comment: I solved the problem, at the moment I'll add 2 footer row. However, in the future, I could have the need to add 2-3-4..n footer rows. Is it possible?

Comment: @GiacomoSavioli: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703037/315935) demonstrates how *manually* add and fill additional row in the footer and how to fill new row. The code just clone the first row of the footer, clan some properties of the row and append it after the first footer row (see call of `insertAfter`). You can use the same code to add mutiple rows in the footer.