# PHP jqGrid footer sum total column only sum the current page

Tags: php, jqgrid

This is my jqgrid footerrow code

```
loadComplete: function() {
            var debit = $("#myDataList").jqGrid('getCol', 'debit', false, 'sum');
            $("#myDataList").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {category: 'Total:', debit: debit});
            var credit = $("#myDataList").jqGrid('getCol', 'credit', false, 'sum');
            $("#myDataList").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {category: 'Total:', credit: credit});
        }
```

I want to cum up two column value debit and credit, my problem now is the total value only sum up the current page but not all.

Comment: which type of data you are using? `local` data or `xml` like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` with `loadonce: true` then more as one page of data will be saved locally in the grid. The array of data is accessible by `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`. So you can enumerate all items of internal data and calculate the sum of all elements from `"debit"` and `"credit"` columns. Then you can use

```js
$(this).jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
    category: "Total:",
    debit: debit,
    credit: credit
});
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703037/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129908/315935) contains code fragments with very close work. In your case it will be about the following code (I didn't tested it):

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        localData = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),
        itemCount = localData.length,
        totalCredit = 0,
        totalDebit = 0,
        i,
        item;

    for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        item = localData[i];
        totalCredit += parseFloat(litem.credit);
        totalDebit += parseFloat(litem.debit);
    }

    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        category: "Total:",
        debit: totalDebit,
        credit: totalCredit
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, it's helpful , but is it possible to display footer that contain summary only on last page?

Comment: @yash: Not directly, but the footer is just a div which you can hide/show inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: but if i hide div than it not display at the last page too, so what can i do if i want to display only on last page? thanks in advance.

Comment: @yash: jqGrid consist from many dives and tables. You should hide only the footer div. If you would have implementation problem you can post **new question** and I'll post my answer with an example of JavaScript code which do this.