# Three footer row with jqgrid is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, salesforce

I need to create a three footer row in jqrid (the idea is to show 3 totals line at the end of the grid). In order to achieve that I fallow this post [How to create two footer rows in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697523/how-to-create-two-footer-rows-in-jqgrid/13703037#13703037) which is really useful from Oleg.

The thing is that I made some changes in his code to show 3 totals lines and is working fine when is the first load of the data, but if you click on next page or any other action it will show the 3 totals lines but on of those is repeated, so i'm loosing the second total.

This is my code:

```
                loadComplete: function () {//for showing default edit
                    var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
                    //In order to have three totals
                    var $this = $(this),
                    $footerRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.footrow"),
                    $secondFooterRow,$thirdFooterRow;
                    var f = '$'+{!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Total_Before_GST__c};
                    var m = '$'+{!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Grand_Total_GST__c};
                    var l = '$'+{!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Grand_Total_After_GST__c};

                    $secondFooterRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.myfootrow");
                    $thirdFooterRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.myfootrow");
                    if ($secondFooterRow.length === 0) {
                        // add second row of the footer if it's not exist
                        $secondFooterRow = $footerRow.clone();
                        $secondFooterRow.removeClass("footrow").addClass("myfootrow ui-widget-content");
                        $secondFooterRow.children("td").each(function () {
                            this.style.width = ""; // remove width from inline CSS
                        });
                        $secondFooterRow.insertAfter($footerRow);
                    }      
                    if ($thirdFooterRow.length === 0) {
                        // add second row of the footer if it's not exist
                        $thirdFooterRow = $secondFooterRow.clone();
                        $thirdFooterRow.removeClass("footrow").addClass("myfootrow ui-widget-content");
                        $thirdFooterRow.children("td").each(function () {
                            this.style.width = ""; // remove width from inline CSS
                        });
                        $thirdFooterRow.insertAfter($secondFooterRow);
                    }                                    
                    //FIRST FOOTER ROW
                    $this.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {Description1__c: "Total EX GST:", Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c:f});
                    //$this.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {Description1__c: "Total XXX GST:", Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c:f});
                    //SECOND FOOTER ROW
                    $secondFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Description1__c]").text("GST:");
                    $secondFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").text(m);
                    //THIRD FOOTER ROW
                    $thirdFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Description1__c]").text("Total INC GST:");
                    $thirdFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").text(l);

                }
```

Here it is how it looks with the first load of the page:

```
    Total EX GST:   $1,141.12
    GST:            $114.14
    Total INC GST:  $1255.26
```

Page 
2 of 2
View 11 - 12 of 12

And this how it looks when I click on next page or any other action:

```
    Total EX GST:   $1,141.12
    Total INC GST:  $1255.26
    Total INC GST:  $1255.26
```

Page 
2 of 2
View 11 - 12 of 12

Any advice will be really appreciate it. I'm using this jqgrid in Salesforce but in the end is just a HTML page. I wanted to upload the images but i'm new in the community, so I can't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone with the same problem, if you specify a unique Id, then you can reference that Id and update it. Here the solution of the question above:

```
                    loadComplete: function () {//for showing default edit
                    var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    }
                    //In order to have three totals
                    var $this = $(this),
                    $footerRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.footrow"),
                    $secondFooterRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.myfootrow"),
                    $thirdFooterRow = $(this.grid.sDiv).find("tr.mythirdfootrow");

                    //$secondFooterRow,$thirdFooterRow;
                    var f = {!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Total_Before_GST__c};
                    var m = custFormat({!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Grand_Total_GST__c});
                    var l = custFormat({!optyObj.Otter_FFA_Grand_Total_After_GST__c});


                    if ($secondFooterRow.length === 0) {
                        // add second row of the footer if it's not exist
                        $secondFooterRow = $footerRow.clone();
                        $secondFooterRow.removeClass("footrow").addClass("myfootrow ui-widget-content");
                        $secondFooterRow.attr('id', 'secondFooterRow');
                        $secondFooterRow.children("td").each(function () {
                            this.style.width = ""; // remove width from inline CSS
                        });
                        $secondFooterRow.insertAfter($footerRow);
                    }      

                    if ($thirdFooterRow.length === 0) {
                        // add second row of the footer if it's not exist
                        $thirdFooterRow = $footerRow.clone();
                        $thirdFooterRow.removeClass("footrow").addClass("mythirdfootrow ui-widget-content");
                        $thirdFooterRow.attr('id', 'thirdFooterRow');
                        $thirdFooterRow.children("td").each(function () {
                            this.style.width = ""; // remove width from inline CSS
                        });
                        $thirdFooterRow.insertAfter($secondFooterRow);
                    } 

                    //FIRST FOOTER ROW
                    //$this.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {Description1__c: "Total EX GST:<br><br>GST:<br><br>Total INC GST:", Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c:f}, {Description1__c: "Total EX GST:<br><br>GST:<br><br>Total INC GST:", Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c:f});
                    $this.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {Description1__c: "Total EX GST:", Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c:f});
                    //SECOND FOOTER ROW
                    $secondFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Description1__c]").text("GST:");
                    $secondFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").attr('id', 'secondFooterRow_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c');
                    $secondFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").text(m);
                    //THIRD FOOTER ROW
                    $thirdFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Description1__c]").text("Total INC GST:");
                    $thirdFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").attr('id', 'thirdFooterRow_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c');
                    $thirdFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_Otter_FFA_Total_Price__c]").text(l);

                }

            });
```