# How to freeze/lock a row in Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to freeze the bottom row of my grid. I'm thinking of writting a row attrribute for it. Something like this:

```
"rowattr": function (rd) { 
                if (rd.islocked) {
                    return {"frozen":"true"};
                } 
            }
```

Will something like this actually work ? I looked at the example [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns&s[]=frozen), but it didn't work for me.

This is the first time I'm using Jqgrid, so I hva eno idea how to do this. Any help is welcomed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you should just use the footer/summary row of jqGrid. By adding `footerrow: true` option you will inform jqGrid to create additional "footer row" at the bottom of the grid. To fill the row with data you can either use the method [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). It's the way *manual* filling the footer row. Alternatively you can use `userdata` part of input data (or set `userData` parameter) and to use `userDataOnFooter: true` option. In the second way jqGrid will fill the footer using `userdata` as input.

Comment: Thank you ! Last thing to ask - how can I have more than one footer (fixed) row. For example how can I have two ?

Comment: @user3719857: You are welcome! It's not possible directly, but I posted [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703037/315935) where I described the way of adding multiple footer rows.