# How to enable grouping with summary footer for each group in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jqgrid

I have displayed data from server into jqgrid .Now as per my need i have to enable grouping with summary footer for each group of data, but i have no idea how to implement this in JQGRID..
I am using JSP as server side code for fetching data from database. After fetching data, manually i am converting into JSON type..

Here is my client side code..

```
        var i=1;
        $('#go').click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            fromdate=$('#fromdate').val();
            todate=$('#todate').val();
            if(fromdate && todate)
            {  
                var URL='getGriddahico.jsp';
                if(i==1){gridcall(URL);}
                else{jQuery("#gridUsuarios").jqGrid('GridUnload');gridcall(URL);}
                i++; 
            }

        });

    });

    function gridcall(path)
    {
        jQuery("#gridUsuarios").jqGrid({
            url:path,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['ID','Call Date','Call Time','Source','DialedNo','Extension'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:90,align: 'center',editable:true, hidden:true,closed:true},
                {name:'date',index:'date',editable:false, width:150,align: 'center'},
                {name:'time',index:'time',editable:false, width:150,align: 'center'},
                {name:'source',index:'source',editable:false, width:170,align: 'center'},
                {name:'destination',index:'destination',editable:false, width:170,align: 'center'}
            ],
            rowNum:50,
            rowList:[50,100,150],
            scrollrows : true,
            pager: '#pagGrid',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            autowidth:true,
            toppager: true,
            height:470


        });
        // Set navigator with search enabled.
        jQuery("#gridUsuarios").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagGrid',{cloneToTop:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:false})
```

And here is my jsp code where i am converting data fetched from database into JSON and sending it to Client side code...

```
int start = 0;
int total = 0;
int total_pages = 0;

int intpage = new Integer(request.getParameter("page"));
int limit = new Integer(request.getParameter("rows"));

String sidx = request.getParameter("sidx");
String sord = request.getParameter("sord");
String strQuery = "";
String json = "";

boolean rc;

ResultSet rs = null;

if (sidx == "") {
    sidx = "1";
}


/*
 * -----------------------------------Conexión to MySql-------------------------------------------
 */
conexion conexiondb = new conexion();
conexiondb.Conectar();
/*
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

total = conexiondb.countRec("id", "processeddata_table", query);

if (total > 0) {
    double d = Math.ceil((double) (total) / (double) (limit));
    total_pages = (int) (d);
} else {
    total_pages = 0;
}

if (intpage > total_pages) {
    intpage = total_pages;
}

start = limit * intpage - limit;

if (start < 0) {
    start = 0;
}
 System.out.println(query);
 strQuery = "SELECT *,date(calldate) as date,time(calldate) as time FROM processeddata_table where date(calldate) between '" + query + "  ORDER BY " + sidx + " " + sord + " LIMIT " + start + " , " + limit;
System.out.println(strQuery);

rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

total = conexiondb.countRec("id", "processeddata_table", query);


response.setContentType("text/x-json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

json = "";
json = json + "{\n";
json = json + " \"page\":\"" + intpage + "\",\n";
json = json + "\"total\":" + total_pages + ",\n";
json = json + "\"records\":" + total + ",\n";
json = json + "\"rows\": [";
rc = false;

while (rs.next()) {

    if (rc) {
        json = json + ",";
    }
    json = json + "\n{";
    json = json + "\"id\":\"" + rs.getInt("id") + "\",";
    json = json + "\"cell\":[" + rs.getInt("id") + "";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("date") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("time") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("source") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("destination") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("extension") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("trunk") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("duration") + "\"";

    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("toc") + "\"";

    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("callcost") + "\"";
    json = json + ",\"" + rs.getString("Site") + "\"]";
    json = json + "}";

    rc = true;
}
json = json + "]\n";

json = json + "}";

out.print(json);
out.close();
```

Please help me to solve this issue ..
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For do grouping you need to have the following grid configuration should added to your code.

```
grouping:true, 
groupingView : { 
         groupField : ['column_name'], 
         groupSummary : [true], 
         groupColumnShow : [true], 
         groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
         groupCollapse : false, 
         groupOrder: ['asc'] 
}
```

This will help you to configure grouping your data. For more details about grouping and summary footer data check the [jQgrid Demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and check grouping in that refer summary footers. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response now grouping is happening but summary is not coming ..Please guide me how to show summary..

Comment: Try this vikas `var grid = $("#grid_id"),
    sum = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'column_name', false, 'sum');

grid.jqGrid('footerData','set', {ID: 'Total:', column_name: sum});`. Also go through this link [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392987/jqgrid-total-amount-row). By the way you need to configure like this for enable footerrow ` footerrow: true,`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ..i added formatter:'number',summaryType:'sum'  in one of my column and summary is coming but here one issue occurred where group summary is coming for each page of the grouped field whereas i need only once at last of each gorup field containing the total summary of all values present in all page for that grouped field..

Comment: You are welcome vikas. Mark this as answer, so others will make use of this answer.

Comment: make your group summary from true to false. Like this, `groupSummary : [false],`