# jqgrid highest value in a column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which I have 7 column and one of them in time in milliseconds.

Is there a way by which I can get the highest value form a particular column?

In short what I need is the the complete row details whether time taken is the highest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `footerrow: true` option to add footer row to the grid. Additionally you can place some additional code in `loadComplete` which fill the footer on every refilling of the grid. The code in `loadComplete` can call `getCol` method with `"max"` as the value for the last `mathoperation` parameter. It will get you the required value. Then you need just call `footerData` with `"set"` action to set the calculated value in the corresponding column of the footer row. Look the demo from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393740/315935). You need just replace "sum" operation used in the demo to the `"max"`.